# Splash ImageView for my Android application

Tags: android, imageview, splash-screen

I have create ImageView for my splash logo. 
I put it to main.xml:

```
android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:src="@drawable/my_splash2
```

Create new class:

```
package com.example.gotquest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Splash extends Main{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashscreen); 
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = STOPSPLASH;
        splashHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, SPLASHTIME);
    }

    private static final int STOPSPLASH = 0;
    private static final long SPLASHTIME = 3000; 
    private ImageView splash;

    private Handler splashHandler = new Handler() { 
             public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                 switch (msg.what) {
                 case STOPSPLASH:

                     splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                     break;
                 }
                 super.handleMessage(msg);
             }
          };
}
```

and added to manifest file this string for loading my splash first:

```
android:name=".Splash"
```

When splash ends, I can see my layout, but buttons and other don't work. I think, splash ImageView becomes invisible, but covers another items.
How can I fix it?

Comment: you havent intiliazed you buttons in Main

Comment: rajan ks, all worked normally, until i've create splash

Answer (score 0):

> but buttons and other don't work. I think, splash ImageView becomes
>   invisible, but covers another items. How i can fix
>   it?

No it doesn't cover the other widgets. Remember that whit `setVisibility(View.GONE);`, Android will not either layout the widget. The buttons aren't working because you didn't define any behavior for them. You probably want to use `setOnClickListener` on the button's reference (that you can't always retrieve with `findViewById`), and define the button's behavior in the `onClick`'s callback

Comment: no,  i've defined the button's behavior: 
`Button button_for_exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
  button_for_exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.exit(0);
   }
  });`  
and for other my buttons too